# Playing sequence of small sound buffers continuosly with Web Audio Api

Tags: web-audio-api

I like to generate sound from an arbitrary mathematical function f(x). Now I use AudioBufferSource for this, and its onended handler I create and play another source for the next buffer and so on. The problem is the crackles between the buffers. Here is my example code:

```
function init() {
        var contextClass = (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext
                || mozAudioContext || oAudioContext || msAudioContext);
        if (contextClass) {
            // Web Audio API is available.
            context = new contextClass();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

// arbitary mathematical function (not just sin)
function mySoundFunction(i, j, k) {
    return j*Math.sin(i/10);
}
function createBufferSource(j) {
        var length = 8092;

        var audioBuffer = context.createBuffer(1, length, 44500);
        var data = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            data[i] = mySoundFunction(i, j, 5);
        }

        var source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.onended = function ended(obj) {
           createBufferSource(j);
    }

        source.start(0);

    }


if (init()) {
    console.log("init was successful");
}
createBufferSource(0.1);
```

As the mathematical function can be changed by user while sound is playing, buffer sizes must be kept small, and prebuffering is not a real option because of latency. ScriptProcessor might be an alternate but it is too expensive in performance, I guess. As the function can be anything, OscillatorNode is not good too.
So the question is, how the crackles between two buffers can be eliminated?
thanks

I tried to use ScriptProcessor but it still have gaps

```
function feed() {
    var a = j === 0 ? 5000: 6000;
    for (var i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
        audata[i] = Math.sin(a*k);
        k++;
    }

    j = 1-j ;
}


function createProcessor() {

    processor = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 0, 1);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {;    
        var L = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);

         L.set(audata);
         feed();
           }

        processor.connect(context.destination);

    running=true;
}


if (init()) {
    console.log("init was successful");
}

audata = new Float32Array(2048);
k=0;
j=1;
feed();
createProcessor();
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use onended here.  That WILL leave a gap, because it's fired after the audio finishes playing in the audio thread, so there's a substantial gap.

You probably want to use ScriptProcessor today, and AudioWorkers in the future.

Comment: I tried ScriptProcessor but something is wrong: see the edited question. Thanks

Comment: hmm.  have you profiled it to make sure it's completing feed() quickly enough?  And have you looked at the audio data generated by feed() to make sure the end of one block is congruent with the beginning of the next?  Doesn't seem like it would be based on the math, but I could be misreading.